# An upper bound on the number of moves

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Given a $ k \in \mathbb{N} $, the integers $ 1,2, \cdots ,4k-1, 4k $ are written on a blackboard. A move consists of replacing the numbers $ a, b, c, a+b+c $ with the numbers $ a+b, b+c, c+a $. Prove that you can perform no more than $ k-1 $ moves.

Comment: So we replace $4$ numbers with $3$ numbers? Do all of $a+b$, $b+c$, and $c+a$ need to be integers from $1$ to $4k$?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't that follow from the problem statement? Since you are erasing $ a+b+c $, this implies $ a+b+c \le 4k $, so the numbers $ a+b,b+c,c+a $ are also less than $ 4k $ (and greater than one, obviously)

Comment: So you can have repeated numbers?

Comment: Yes, you can. If you take $ k=2 $ and choose $ a=1,b=2,c=4 $, after a move you end up with the list $ 3,3,5,5,6,6,8 $.

Comment: This problem is cute.  At each iteration, there is one fewer number on the board, the sum of the numbers remains constant, and the sum of the squares of the numbers remains constant.The sum of the cubes decreases, but only by the product of the $A,b,c$ chosen, and that is not fast enough to get this upper bound.

Comment: What happens to the sum of the positive distances between every pair of numbers?

Comment: Exactly my approach too. The sum of the cubes decreases by $ 6abc $ each move. By Cauchy-Schwarz, the sum of cubes has a lower bound $ \frac{{S_2}^2}{S_1} $, where $ S_2 $ and $ S_1 $ respectively, are the sum of squares of the integers and sum of the integers in the list. (Both are invariant)

Comment: The trouble is, $6abc$ is nowhere near fast enough to be stopping the process at $k-1$ moves.  It is easy to show that you cannot make more than $\frac{4k}{3}$ moves, since every move eats up at least one number at or below $\frac{4k}{3}$.

Comment: And now I can show the limit is no more than $\frac{5k}{4}$ moves, because if I assign 2 starts to each number in $[k,\frac{4k}{3}$ and one star to each number in $(\frac{4k}{3}, \frac{5k}{3})$ then any move that doesn't eat a value below $k$ must chew up at least $4$ stars and we start with only $k$ stars.

Comment: Has anyone made any progress on the problem? This question looks innocent, but is turning out to be the exact opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this question turns out to be a damp squib, having made all those observations in the comments. If $ B $ denotes the collection of numbers at any instant on the board, then by Cauchy-Schwarz, we have

$$ |B| \left( \sum_{b \in B} b^2 \right) \ge \left( \sum_{b \in B} b \right)^2 $$

Noting the fact that the sum as well as sum of squares of the numbers on the board remains invariant, we get

$$ |B| \left(\frac{4k(4k+1)(8k+1)}{6} \right) \ge 4k^2(4k+1)^2 \implies |B| > 3k $$

which ends the proof.

Comment: Nice insight! You should be getting a lot more likes on this one. BTW, what do you mean by "a damp squib"?

Comment: Thank you! I meant that after making the crucial observations about the invariants, it was just straightforward, but we were thinking too much about getting the sum of cubes to decrease fast, i.e we greatly overestimated the difficulty of this problem.!